# Python String Segment Manipulation

Tags: python, string

I have this code so far

```
data = ['fx_name_v002.1001.exr  fx_name_v002.1016.exr'
'fx_name_v002.1002.exr  fx_name_v002.1018.exr']
 data.sort()

frames = []

def string_split(data):
    for i in data:
        print(i.split('.'))
```

I need to split the list like I have. Once the list is split I need to add the 1002, 1001, of the split ends into the empty list frames

Comment: `print(string(string.index('.')))` ?

Comment: I get this error while trying to do that
                               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: What specifically is the output you want? You can use `re.sub()` here.

Comment: the output I want is file_name_name_v3002.$$$$.extension

Comment: You want the second number to be replaced by '$'? If so, please add that expected output to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to substitute patterns in strings.

```
string = ['''file_name_name_v3002.1001.extension
             file_name_name_v3002.1002.extension
             file_name_name_v3002.1003.extension 
             file_name_name_v3002.1004.extension''']

import re
re.sub(r'\.\d{4}\.', '.%%%%.', string[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.sub` with a callable will allow to handle numbers of different sizes.

```
import re

s = '''file_name_name_v3002.1001.extension
file_name_name_v3002.1002.extension
file_name_name_v3002.1003.extension 
file_name_name_v3002.1004.extension'''

new_s = re.sub('(?<=\.)\d+', lambda m: '%' * len(m.group()), s)

print(new_s)
```

### Output

```
file_name_name_v3002.%%%%.extension
file_name_name_v3002.%%%%.extension
file_name_name_v3002.%%%%.extension 
file_name_name_v3002.%%%%.extension
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what regular expressions are made for.

```
import re

expr = re.compile(r'''
  [\w\d_]+                  # one or more a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or underscores (_)
  \.                        # a literal period
  (\d{4})                   # capture four digits
  \.                        # another literal period
  .*$                       # whatever through the end of the string''', re.X)
```

You can use `expr.match(some_string)` to match the value, or reverse the capturing groups to use it as part of re.sub

```
subexpr = re.compile(r"([\w\d_]+\.)\d{4}(\..*)$"
subexpr.sub("\1%%%%\2", some_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = '''file_name_name_v3002.1001.extension
             file_name_name_v3002.1002.extension
             file_name_name_v3002.1003.extension 
             file_name_name_v3002.1004.extension'''.split("\n")
'\n'.join(''.join(x if not x.startswith("1") else "$$$$" for x in e.split(".")) for e in string)
```

You could try a list comprehension